# Python: how to find common values in three lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I try to find common list of values for three different lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
c = [3,4,5,6]
```

of course naturally I try to use the `and` operator however that way I just get the value of last `list` in expression:

```
>> a and b and c
out: [3,4,5,6]
```

Is any short way to find the common values list:

```
[3,4]
```

Br

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use sets:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> set(a) & set(b) & set(c)
{3, 4}
```

Or as Jon suggested:

```
>>> set(a).intersection(b, c)
{3, 4}
```

Using sets has the benefit that you don’t need to repeatedly iterate the original lists. Each list is iterated once to create the sets, and then the sets are intersected.

The naive way to solve this using a filtered list comprehension as Geotob did will iterate lists `b` and `c` for each element of `a`, so for longer list, this will be a lot less efficient.

Comment: Don't forget to turn the result into a list if type is important!

Answer (score 12):

```
out = [x for x in a if x in b and x in c]
```

is a quick and simple solution. This constructs a list `out` with entries from `a`, if those entries are in `b` and `c`.

For larger lists, you want to look at the answer provided by @poke

Answer (score 5):

For those still stumbling uppon this question, with numpy one can use:

```
np.intersect1d(array1, array2)
```

This works with lists as well as numpy arrays. 
It could be extended to more arrays with the help of `functools.reduce`, or it can simply be repeated for several arrays.

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.intersect1d, (array1, array2, array3))
```

or

```
new_array = np.intersect1d(array1, array2)
np.intersect1d(new_array, array3)
```

Comment: brilliant in its simplicity.  Thank-you for this.