# Intersection of lists which are values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

Python 2.7

data structure is like this,

```
hitdict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[2,3,6,5], 'C':[2,3,7,8]}
```

Note the number of key:value pairs is variable.
I want the intersection of A, B, C :

```
[2,3]
```

For intersection of two or more list, most answers suggest either set class or lambda functions.
eg. [intersection of lists of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145319/intersection-of-subelements-of-multiple-list-of-lists-in-dictionary), using [lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

and from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061223/python-how-to-find-common-values-in-three-lists), where `a,b,c` are lists

```
>> set(a) & set(b) & set(c)
```

I have a number of dictionaries like this with variable number of lists.

My main confusion is about how to use the above set(), since 
if I use for loop with `hitdict.items()` it will give k:v pairs only one at a time. Hence the code below is incorrect.

```
for (k,v) in hitdict.items():
    common = set(hitdict[k]) + set(hitdict[k+1])
```

How to do this in Python ?

Comment: I started out 3 months back with python, hence the inability to understand and adopt the answer from Duplicate question.

Comment: In case more than one answer works, 
what is the basis to decide which one to accept ?

Comment: Generally you should accept an answer that helps you most (post your own if none of the answers are satisfactory). Since you've already marked one as accepted, let it be; you can upvote the others to show appreciation. Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` to convert lists  to sets and `reduce` to apply the intersection. Do:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x&y, map(set, hitdict.values()))
```

It gives:

```
set([2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`, with a custom `lambda` and set `intersection` to do that:

```
>>> hitdict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[2,3,6,5], 'C':[2,3,7,8]}
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x.intersection(y), (set(x) for x in hitdict.values()))
set([2, 3])
```

Note that the generator above also ensures that your items are fed one by one to reduce.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:-

```
reduce(lambda value1, value2: set(value1).intersection(set(value2)), hitdict.values())
```